# Simulink model is not seems to work at high frequency [Just a representation mistake ?]

Tags: simulation, simulink, simulate

I have a model of the form:

[image]

All I am doing here is mixing the two sine waveforms based on the random bits.

I set the signal frequency of first sign wave to:
[image]

Second sign wave:

[image]

The output is :
[image]

But it works well when the signals are of low frequency.

How can I make it to work even at high frequencies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`80*10^3*t` and `12*10^4*t` are both always an integer for all values of `t=0:0.01:100`.  Hence the sin is always being evaluated at an integer multiple of `2*pi`.  Hence  the value of the plot is always zero (or near enough to it down in the `10^-8` or `10^-9` range.

You need to change the sample rate so that you get points where sin is not zero.